# Hiding worksheet based on a list

Tags: vba, excel

Hey have a quick question I am writing a code that hides a list of worksheets based on whether the field next to the worksheet name is yes or no. Therefore, I have list of 29 worksheets, I want my code to look at the field next to that name, and if its yes it while show it and if it is no It will hide it.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If ws.Name = Worksheets("Settings").Range("B4:B32") _
        And Worksheets("Setting").Range("C4:C32") = "Yes" Then
            ws.Visible = True
        End If
        If ws.Name = Worksheets("Settings").Range("B4:B32") _
        And Worksheets("Setting").Range("C4:C32") = "No" Then
            ws.Visible = True
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```

I run this and keep getting a mismatch error i am new to programming so i don't think i am calling stuff correctly

Comment: The `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event macro is triggered every time you move from one cell on a worksheet to another on the same worksheet. It is unlikely that you need or want this type of overhead. Suggest you use `Worksheet_Change` (only triggered on changed values) on a limited range of B4:C32. Btw, both of your conditions resolve to a visible worksheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the following code should suit your needs:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim wsSettings As Worksheet
    Dim wsHideShow As Worksheet
    Dim rngSheets As Range
    Dim xlCell As Range
    Dim sheetName As String

    Set wsSettings = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Settings")
    Set rngSheets = wsSettings.Range("B4:B32")

    For Each xlCell In rngSheets
        sheetName = xlCell.Value

        If sheetName <> "" Then

            Set wsHideShow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetName)

            If xlCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "yes" Then
                wsHideShow.Visible = False
            Else
                wsHideShow.Visible = True
            End If
        End If
    Next xlCell

End Sub
```

Instead of looping through your worksheets, loop through your list and hide/show the worksheets accordingly.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please accept my answer by clicking on the corresponding checkmark icon

Comment: Doesn't this trigger whenever *any* cell on the entire worksheet is changed? If the only cells governing the show/hide action are in B4:C32 shouldn't the action be restricted to when those cells change?

Answer (score 0):

Being slow in typing... but... my suggestion would be:

```
Private Sub WorkSheet_Change(ByVal Target as range)

   If (Target.Row >= 4 And Target.Row <= 32 And Target.Column = 2) Then
      Dim i as Integer
      For i=0 To 28 Step 1
         If Range("B" & 2 + i).Value = "YES" Then
           ThisWorkBook.Worksheets(Range("A" & 2 + i).Value).Visible = True
         Else
           ThisWorkBook.Worksheets(Range("A" & 2 + i).Value).Visible = False
         End If
      Next i
   End If

End Sub
```

This is fireing only when the values in the range B4:B32 on the sheet are changed...

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

This code runs in a standard module.  It assumes that the master is **Settings** rather than **Setting**

It loops over the table as well as the sheets:

```
Sub DisplayOrHideSheets()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    For Each ws In Sheets
        v = ws.Name
        For Each r In Worksheets("Settings").Range("B4:B32")
            If r.Value = v Then
                If r.Offset(0, 1) = "Yes" Then
                    ws.Visible = True
                Else
                    ws.Visible = False
                End If
            End If
        Next r
    Next ws
End Sub
```